# Get table id dynamically in gwtquery/jquery

Tags: jquery, gwtquery

I'm having some difficulty in getting the id of a table dynamically in gwtquery.

I've 3 tabbed table each with different table id and I need the id of the table to proceed.

I tried

```
 $(tableData).closest("table").attr("id"));
 $(tableData).parents("table").attr("id"));
```

Both of them doesnt work.

This is how my table looks

```
 <div style="" class="viewArea">
 <div aria-hidden="false" style="" class="overflow">
  <table id="tableId1" class="tableClass">
```

I would like to get the table id dynamically, for table 2 its **tableId2** and so on.

Answer (score 0):

use this function to fetch table values

```
$(function () {
                      var abc = $('table');          
           alert($(abc[0]).attr('id'));
        });
```

above is just a demo, you can use foreach loop to fetch all the values